# Can I make colored lines in an XML file without typing TODO?

Tags: xml, android-studio

In any xml file in Android Studio, any comment with "TODO" highlights the text green after it.

[image: strings.xml TODO green line]

[image: TODO after only]

Are there any other keywords that change text color like this?

Is there any way I can make my Layout Margins comment green or another color without calling it "TODO Layout Margins"?

I really just want a way of highlighting sections within my style.xml file the way that these TODO comments are highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > XML > Comment

Just uncheck the `Inherit values from` checkbox and customize the color schemes.